# Что я делаю не так? проблема в верстке

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

http://jsfiddle.net/b6Ywr/1/

```css
.menu {
  width: 980px;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu .nav {
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.nav>li:first-child a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px;
  border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  display: block;
  height: 37px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  line-height: 37px;
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav ul {
  background: #e26704;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e26704 0%, #fe9921 38%, #fe9921 62%, #e26704 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #e26704), color-stop(38%, #fe9921), color-stop(62%, #fe9921), color-stop(100%, #e26704));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e26704 0%, #fe9921 38%, #fe9921 62%, #e26704 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e26704 0%, #fe9921 38%, #fe9921 62%, #e26704 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e26704 0%, #fe9921 38%, #fe9921 62%, #e26704 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e26704 0%, #fe9921 38%, #fe9921 62%, #e26704 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e26704', endColorstr='#e26704', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1110;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  background: #de6100;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #de6100 0%, #ff9922 40%, #ff9922 60%, #de6100 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #de6100), color-stop(40%, #ff9922), color-stop(60%, #ff9922), color-stop(100%, #de6100));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #de6100 0%, #ff9922 40%, #ff9922 60%, #de6100 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #de6100 0%, #ff9922 40%, #ff9922 60%, #de6100 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #de6100 0%, #ff9922 40%, #ff9922 60%, #de6100 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #de6100 0%, #ff9922 40%, #ff9922 60%, #de6100 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#de6100', endColorstr='#de6100', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.nav ul a {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav ul li {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.nav ul a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="clearfix nav">
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>i>
    <li><a href="#">Документы</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Выпадающее меню</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню тянется по ширине</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Лицензии</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Нормативы</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">С чего начать</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

При наведении на "Документы", подпункты должны тянуться. Уже столько перепробовал всего, не получается, не знаю как. Помогите пожалуйста исправить эту проблемку!

Comment: [так ?](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/b6Ywr/4/)

Comment: да, так. Спасибо. Но я только не нашел, что вы исправили? а то хочу понять как это сделали

Comment: Думаю господин @eicto сделал white-space: nowrap; у суб меню.